# What are the xcuserstate files used for?

Tags: xcode

When committing changes to `GIT` repo, i see constant updates coming from the `xcuserstate`  files.

What are those?

Comment: delete them and see how Xcode goes back to it's default layouts and window positioning. They will automatically regenerate them too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xcuserstate files are generated from within Xcode and saved in your project bundle to remember your last opened file, the open state of any group folders, open tabs, and any other user setting your project might need to remember. For purposes of revision control, you should ignore them or leave them out if at all possible.